# Cakephp and PHP: How to change xml value in xml?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2

I want to update to_status value.

I have following xml file.

```
<challenges>
  <challenge>
     <challenge_id>1385</challenge_id> 
     <debate_id>988</debate_id> 
     <comment_id>157</comment_id> 
     <from_id>42</from_id> 
     <to_id>3</to_id> 
     <from_status> true</from_status>
     <to_status> false</to_status>
     <timestamp>1320933898</timestamp> 
  </challenge>
</challenges>
```

How can i update it?

Comment: Is really vague, what have you tried?

Comment: http://bit.ly/vZqYwD have you tried this??

Answer (score 0):

Look into CakePHP's "XML" class. In versions prior to 2.0, you have to "App::import('Xml')" the XML class but in 2.0 it is a core library.

With the XML class, you can render the XML as an array, manipulate it the way you want, and simply re-transform it into an XML string.

Check out these links:

CakePHP 1.3 XML : http://book.cakephp.org/view/1473/XML

CakePHP 2.0 XML : http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/xml.html?highlight=xml